# What are the limitations of the 6.765 - 6.975 MHz ISM band in the United States?

Tags: united-states, legal, fcc, band-plan

[image: https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/spectrum/table/fcctable.pdf]
[There is a region of the lower 43 meter band designated for ISM use in the United States by the FCC starting at 6.765 MHz and ending at 6.975 MHz](https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/spectrum/table/fcctable.pdf). Both "FIXED" and "MOBILE" usage is allowed per FCC guidelines. There is a lack of documentation on this designation but from what I could find there are MRI machines and industrial equipment that use this frequency range. Could you use this portion of the ISM band for normal HF communication? For example, if I wanted to send data using a HF transmitter operating at 100 watts and a dipole antenna resonant at the center frequency 6.78 MHz. Would this be permitted over this segment of the ISM band?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Your question is off-topic, unfortunately, and will therefore soon be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Operation of industrial, scientific, and medical (ISM) equipment that radiates RF is governed by [47 CFR Part 18](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-18) in the US.  When dealing with federal law regarding radio topics, I quickly find myself going to the source text, rather than relying on some web site to interpret it for me.  Warning: I'm no lawyer, so take what I say with a grain of salt; this post is certainly not meant to be legal advice.

I didn't read all of Part 18; I just skipped to [Subpart C - Technical Standards](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-18/subpart-C).  I found it interesting that there is no power limit to energy radiated within the ISM bands.  However, there is a limit to the strength of the electric field emitted at frequencies outside the ISM band, and to the RF voltage conducted back to the electric mains.  In practice these factors probably limits the power one could emit inside the band, because existing radio technology doesn't allow radiation at a narrow range of frequencies, and there are limits to the efficiency of bandpass filters.  There are also limits to the allowed RF exposure to humans.

I couldn't find any restrictions to operating modes or anything like that.  I'd have to say that according to my quick scan of Subpart C, it looks as though it would be legal for you to use a homebrew transmitter on the "44m" ISM band, which is from 6.765 to 6.795 according to Table 1 in [§ 18.301](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/18.301).  I think that the difficulty might be noise from diathermy machines, induction cook tops, etc. radiating on that band.  Someone with a general-coverage receiver and a suitable antenna could listen to that band to see how loud it actually is.